# Creating a sidebar help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm setting up a world that increases in size each Minecraft day but I can't get the sidebar to work. How can make a sidebar that displays the size of the world border?

Answer (score 4):

You must use the `QueryResult` CommandStat to obtain the worldborder size as a score.

**Prerequisites:**

Objective to hold the worldborder size.

```
/scoreboard objectives add INFO dummy
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar INFO
```

In order for CommandStats to modify a target's score, that target must be tracked on the scoreboard prior.

```
/scoreboard players set WorldBorder INFO 0
```

**Detection:**

Insert the following into a command block on a clock.

```
/worldborder get
```

Whenever the command runs, it will reurn a `QueryResult` value equal to the worldborder size. However, that return value is useless without applying a trigger to the command block.

Stand on top of the command block and run the following command yourself a single time:

```
/stats block ~ ~-1 ~ set QueryResult WorldBorder INFO
```

Now whenever the command block runs its stored command, and that command returns a `QueryResult` value, fake player WorldBorder will have their "INFO" score set equal to that return value.

Comment: @RNH If their answer worked for you, you should press the tick to the left of the answer to mark it as accepted.